# Can private flights between the US and Canada avoid using a port of entry?

Tags: general-aviation, usa, international, canada

I'm considering getting back into flying private after a 15 year absence. I'm a dual US/Canadian passport holder. I'd like to fly between homes on Nantucket, MA and rural Nova Scotia regularly. Is there any type of permit that would provide an exemption from landing at a port of entry every time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[CANPASS](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/canpass/privateair-eng.html) gives a streamlined entry into Canada, allowing you to land at a port of entry and just report by phone.  To go into the US, you [need](https://www.aopa.org/travel/international-travel/eapis-frequently-asked-questions) an [eAPIS account](https://eapis.cbp.dhs.gov/auth/login.html?resource_url=https%3A%2F%2Feapis.cbp.dhs.gov%2Feapis%2Flogin).  I think that with eAPIS you still need to meet in person with a customs person.  A friend in Montreal used eAPIS to travel to Vermont regularly.  He said it was a lot of hassle to get set up and go through the process the first time, but after that it was not too bad.  On the way back he just had to land at a convenient POE and call in.

Not quite an avoidance of POE requirements, but otherwise pretty convenient.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, **no**. There are simply too many people who would abuse such a permit to commit crimes for either country to accept the risk.

You will need a stop at a Port of Entry or User Fee (US) airport in each direction to clear customs and immigration, but at least it should be quick since you are a citizen of both countries, and there appear to be several along your likely route of travel to choose from. Then you can continue on as a domestic flight to wherever you want, including a private strip.

You’d think that Nantucket (ACK/KACK) would be large enough and busy enough to be at least a US Customs User Fee airport, which would solve half your problem, but apparently not.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. I was hoping there was some qualifying-type blanket clearance that I was unaware of, but alas I understand the reasoning.

Comment: @DeanG - Don’t forget that you may need a DTOPS Decal for the aircraft as well. You will still need to land at an AOE.